# javascript to change tabs using Amazon Mechanical Turk <crowd-tabs>

Tags: javascript, tabs, mechanicalturk

I am using Amazon Mechanical Turk's new `<crowd-form>` tags and am creating a paid qualifier with 2 tabs, one for instructions and practice with our interface, and one for the test itself.  I'd like to put a button at the bottom of the instruction tab to allow the user to proceed easily to the test tab without having to scroll all the way back up to the top. Is there an easy way to do this with Amazon's special `<crowd-tabs>` elements?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need any JavaScript to achieve this.

Here is a code sample that achieves it:

```
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>

<crowd-form>
  <crowd-tabs id="tabs">
    <crowd-tab header="Tab 1">
      Tab 1 content
    </crowd-tab>

    <crowd-tab header="Tab 2">
      Tab 2 content
    </crowd-tab>
  </crowd-tabs>
</crowd-form>

<crowd-button onclick="tabs.activeIndex=0">
  Tab 1
</crowd-button>

<crowd-button onclick="tabs.activeIndex=1">
  Tab 2
</crowd-button>
```

And here's a working JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/py91rekd.

All the best,

Amazon Mechanical Turk

Comment: That's great.  Is there any way to make it scroll "back" to the top of the newly activated tab?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't quite work. Once you've used one of the buttons to change the active tab, the tabs themselves don't work. (That is, if I use the button to go to tab2, then clicking on the tab1 tab doesn't allow me to switch back to tab1